# Binding AngularJS ng-click in jointJS markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jointjs

I have a custom jointjs element with custom svg markup, something like this:

```
markup: '<g><circle/><path/><g>'
```

I want to bind an angular controller function in `<path ng-click="foo()">` how can I achieve that?

setting via `attrs { path : {'ng-click': foo}}` doesn't work.

Comment: you want to add an angular binding using backbone?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Actually i want to call defined functions in angular controllers from there, paths are triangle shapes around a circle and are clickable.

Comment: My concern is mostly Backbone, where is Backbone relevant here?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Entire code base is based on angular, backbone is not used.

Comment: Then why the backbone.js tag?

Comment: Because jointjs is based on backbone, and all of  nodes and relations is backbone models and views.

Comment: Please add what you have done as of now, what doesn't work, and what is the expected result. A minimal snippet of code would also help, and if there's no backbone in the question itself, you should remove the tag as it is irrelevant.

Comment: also, `{'ng-click'= foo}` is invalid JS, `{'ng-click': foo}` would be a step forward.

Comment: Thanks in advance, it's a typo mistake in this code snippet.